# Pulling data from Netezza db to amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, netezza

I am trying to pull the data from Netezza database and place the returned result in the S3.

Comment: So, you're trying that. Maybe you should tell what happens or what the problem is?

Comment: Current system is running on hadoop. Now i have been assigned the migration task. I am new to AWS not sure how to get it done. Any help as what i should look for will be helpful. Running the query in java application and deploying the jar in emr will take lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream Netezza nzsql output to Amazon S3 bucket using AWS CLI. 
Combination of nzsql command and aws cli will upload Netezza stream data into Amazon S3.

```
$ nzsql -host 192.168.0.111 -u admin -pw password -db training -F ',' -A -t -c "select * from patient_1" | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/upload/test.txt

$ aws s3 ls s3://testnetezzabucket/upload/
2017-11-14 09:08:31 0 
2017-11-14 18:05:04 506 nz_data.txt
2017-11-14 17:57:32 42 test.txt
$
```

Follow [Export Netezza Data into Amazon S3 Bucket](http://dwgeek.com/different-methods-export-netezza-data-into-amazon-s3-bucket.html/)